# latex newenvironment label

Tags: latex

I have the following `newenvironment` command:

```
\newcounter{algoctr}[chapter] \setcounter{algoctr}{0}
\newenvironment{algo}[1] {
\refstepcounter{algoctr}\vspace{0.2cm}\noindent{\bf Algorithm
\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{algoctr}: #1}}{\par}
```

and I use it thusly

```
\begin{algo}{blabbing a blah}
 blah
 blah
\label{eq:blabbing}
\end{algo}
```

However, every time I reference the label (\ref{eq:blabbing}), I get a "1", instead of a "1.1".

Could someone kindly let me know what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're almost there, you just need to redefine `\thealgoctr` as well, something like:

```
\renewcommand\thealgoctr{\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{algoctr}}
```

(Untested.)
And then use `\thealgoctr` in your environment rather than explicitly referring to the counters.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about your counter, but I can recommend another possibility in which this works:

```
\usepackage{amsthm}

\newtheoremstyle{algostyle}
  {0.2cm}{0cm}%                                 margin top and bottom
  {\rmfamily}%                                  text layout
  {0cm}%                                        indention of header
  {\bfseries}{ }%                               header font and text after
  {0cm}%                                        space after header
  {\thmname{#1}\thmnumber{ #2}:\thmnote{ #3}}%  header

\theoremstyle{algostyle}
\newtheorem{algo}{Algorithm}[chapter]

\begin{algo}[blabbing a blah]%  brackets instead of curly braces for note
 blah
 blah
\label{eq:blabbing}
\end{algo}
```